# 0MB Free Space in partition when setting up Ubuntu/Win10 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

Currently trying to install Ubuntu on my Windows 10 desktop to be dual-bootable. I'm following along [this installation guide](http://linuxbsdos.com/2016/06/05/dual-boot-ubuntu-16-04-and-windows-10-on-a-pc-with-uefi-firmware/). I used the guide from Ubuntu's site to create my bootable USB, I did that successfully.

**Current situation:** I've booted from my UEFI USB, started the install process, and now I'm at the part in the guide: "Figure 3: Advanced partitioning tool of Ubuntu". My free space shows 0MB, so why is it not showing either of my hard drives as having free space for this? Or did the guide skip over something crucial where I have to tell it where to look for this space?
[Picture of my partition page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD182.jpg).

**General install question**: The guide says "it will not create a separate partition for your files and folders" if I select the first option, which is to install it alongside the Windows Boot Manager. What is the effective difference here? Would they really make it the number 1, easy choice if I couldn't save things? Or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: I am not a dual boot expert but a cursory look indicates that your Windows installation is consuming your entire SDD drive (sdb).  Probably the quickest way to fix this is to install a second SDD and use that for the Ubuntu install.  As an aside, I don't see the sda partitions listed in your screenshot.  If sda is not in use by any other OS, have Ubuntu format, partition and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The guide glossed over the "shrink the C drive".  Do that from Windows, defrag the drive, then shrink the partition from the right (from the end), then run chkdsk on it a few times to ensure things are OK.  Free up at least 20-30G for Ubuntu, and at least 2G for swap.  With this space left free, the installer should use it to create a root and swap.

The comment about "not creating a separate partition for your files" just means that a separate /home will not be created separate from root.  Some people prefer to keep their files separated that way, but really, you would use a separate data partition, mounted in your home so the "hidden" config files in your home will be associated with the root, and it's installed versions of programs.

Comment: Thanks - I've followed [this Dummies guide](http://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-shrink-a-hard-drive-volume-in-windows/) to shrink part of my G drive (1TB total, shrunk 100GB for good measure). It's now "unallocated" according to the disk management, which the guide informed me it'd be.  
I'll update in a bit if everything worked!